# Matplotlib: changing datetime ticks makes plot disappear

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

im having serious trouble modifying how and which x-axis labels are presented in my plot.

I have a datetime index and want to reduce the number of xticks been shown and remove the year from it. Should be simple, right?! But, for some reason, the plot disappears after i set major formatter and locator. Here is a working example:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

teste = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01','2019-12-31',freq='2D'),columns=['A','B','C'])
teste['A']=.4
teste['B']=.5
teste['C']=.1

for col in teste.columns:
    variation = np.random.rand(len(teste))
    teste[col]+=variation/10.0

teste['total']=teste.sum(axis=1)

for col in teste.columns:
    teste[col]/=teste['total']

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(24,10)).add_axes([0,0,1,1])

teste.drop('total',axis=1).plot(kind='bar',stacked='True',ax=ax,width=1,colormap='coolwarm')
ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_title('Teste',fontsize=28)
ax.set_ylabel('Share (%)',fontsize=22)
ax.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=20)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),fontsize=22, loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image: result from previous code]
As you can see, the xticks are unreadable. But when i try to format:

```
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(24,10)).add_axes([0,0,1,1])

teste.drop('total',axis=1).plot(kind='bar',stacked='True',ax=ax,width=1,colormap='RdBu')
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m"))
ax.set_xlim(teste.index[0],teste.index[-1])
ax.margins(0)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_title('Teste',fontsize=28)
ax.set_ylabel('Share (%)',fontsize=22)
ax.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=20)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),fontsize=22, loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]

The plot vanishes. What am i doing wrong? I`ve tried everything. plt.MaxNLocator(N=10) also doesn't work. It spreads the first N points all over the axis, completely disregarding where it actually should be.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Edit: @Trenton McKinney:

Removing ax.set_xlim(teste.index[0],teste.index[-1]) makes the plot appear but without the xticks.

[image]

Comment: `drop` is a panda's routine.  I'm not sure that the matplotlib locators work with their datetime handling?

Comment: I added an alternative that allows for the use of `set_major_locator` & `set_major_formatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I used the method shown on the Matplotlib website: [Stacked Bar Graph](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py)
- With a bar plot, every bar has a location [0, ..., n]
- `ind` selects the locs to label
- `dates` are the names of the selected ticks

```py
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(24,10)).add_axes([0,0,1,1])

teste.drop('total',axis=1).plot(kind='bar',stacked='True',ax=ax,width=1,colormap='RdBu')

# locations of tick marks to label
ind = np.arange(0, len(teste.index)+1, 10)

# label for ticks
dates = teste.index.date[0::10]  # %y-%m-%d format
# dates = teste.index.strftime('%d/%m')[0::10]  # %d/%m format

# set the xticks
plt.xticks(ind, dates)

# only used to show locs and labels if you're having trouble
# locs, labels = plt.xticks()
# label_t = [x.get_text() for x in labels]

# formatting
ax.margins(0)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_title('Teste',fontsize=28)
ax.set_ylabel('Share (%)',fontsize=22)
ax.tick_params(axis='both',labelsize=20)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),fontsize=22, loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Optionally

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))

p1 = ax.bar(teste.index, teste.A)
p2 = ax.bar(teste.index, teste.B, bottom=teste.A)
p3 = ax.bar(teste.index, teste.C, bottom=teste.A+teste.B)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m"))
ax.set_xlim(teste.index[0],teste.index[-1])

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')  # or (rotation=90, ha='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a lot better but we still have the problem of changing the labels in order to show only month and day.  DateFormatter still doesnt work . I guess for stacked bar plots everything ends up being kinda 'hacky'. 
I managed to make it work but the code looks awful.
But it work so, thats all that matter at this point. Thank you.

Comment: @MatheusCalvelli All you need to do is change `dates = teste.index.date[0::10]` to `dates = teste.index.strftime('%d/%m')[0::10]`